# How to test response which getting received in callback of Promise?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a test case like below

```
it('should get response as expected', () => {
    const expected = {test: 'test};
    serviceRequest().then((response) => {
        expect(response).toEqual(expected);
    })
});
```

It always getting passed, no matter what is there in expectation match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least a couple of options... if you return your Promise, Jest will wait until that promise resolves

```
it('should get response as expected', () => {
    const expected = {test: 'test};
    return serviceRequest().then((response) => {
        expect(response).toEqual(expected);
    })
});
```

Or (my preference), you can make your test `async`. If you do that then you can just await your response and check it on the next line:

```
it('should get response as expected', async () => {
    const expected = {test: 'test};
    await response = serviceRequest();
    expect(response).toEqual(expected);
});
```

The Jest docs cover these and other considerations - [see here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply but it is not working at all. Jest is not waiting for promise to be resolved in first option. I tried "expect(response).toEqual('blah blah blah')" but it got passed.

for second one , it's throwing error saying can't use "await" outside of a async function.

Comment: the second one will work too - notice the extra `async` before the () => on the first line

Comment: After adding 'async' it's saying "invalid left-hand side assignment expression" for 'await'.

Comment: can you post your await line?

Comment: "await response = serviceRequest(params)(dispatch).then(res => res);"

Comment: you can't `await` and `.then` together - it's one or the other. Remove your .then(res => res) from the end.

Comment: No luck, it's saying same after "await response = serviceRequest(params)(dispatch);".

Comment: Forgot to update this post. First answer worked for me. Thank you @Will Jenkins